# Join containing mid function

Tags: sql, ms-access, substring, left-join

I am trying to request with a mid in the ON clause

```
SELECT ....
FROM T1 as t1 LEFT JOIN T2 as t2 on MID(t1.f1, 1, 13) = MID(t2.f2, 1, 13)
```

And It refuse to work

```
JOIN expression not supported
```

If I run the exact same query without the mid It work perfectly fine (execpt I don't get the walue I want)

I tryed to externalise the mids into two request. But It still didn't work with the mid (and work without).

How can I do this request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Access only supports joining by field value, not by expression.  You can join subqueries, though:

```
SELECT ....
FROM (SELECT *, MID(t1.f1, 1, 13) KeyValue FROM T1) as t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, MID(t2.f2, 1, 13) KeyValue FROM T2) as t2
    ON t1.KeyValue = t2.KeyValue
```

Comment: I was going to say use WHERE, but then I noticed it was meant to be a LEFT join, so... Yeah, +1.

Comment: That what I tried to do, When I said I externalise into two request, and It still don't work

Comment: the same : JOIN expression not supported

Comment: access supports joining also by expression

Comment: fthiella : What do you mean ?